# Can I inspect html emails in Thunderbird?

Tags: html, email, firebug, thunderbird, inspector

Is there a way to inspect HTML emails in Thunderbird. In my case on a mac.

I'm getting an error (wrong rendering) that comes up only in Thunderbird so I would need to inspect there if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Thunderbird for Linux, but hopefully the same for Mac:

Tools > Developer Tools > Developer Toolbox

If you get a security warning, accept the risk as it's only your local 127.0.0.1.

Size the window so it doesn't cover the contents of the email.

Click the element picker (arrow top left) then pick the element to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

DOM inspector for Thunderbird : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/dom-inspector-6622/

Comment: The extension prompts me for the URL of a webpage, when I want to inspect an email message...

Comment: This addon does not inspect HTML, but rather the DOM, which is significantly more difficult to interpret.